# AngularJS filter: how to filter with variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to make my filter dynamic for more then one property.
this is the filter line:

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="selectedCard in Cards | filter:{property:filterValue}">
```

I'm getting the var 'property' and the var 'filterValue' from this:

```
<li><a type="button" ng-click="filterValue = 'adventeg' ;property = 'Type'">adventeg</a></li>
```

or from this line:

```
<a type="button" ng-click="search=!search;property='Name'" ng-show="!search" class="nav-hover" title="s" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" tooltip>
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>

<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" ng-show="search" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="filterValue">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="search=!search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </form>
```

for some reason the var 'property' doesn't work in the filter segment. I have already checked manually if the filter works without the var 'property', and it does, why with the var it doesn't?

Comment: You have a typo in your `ng-click`, your `filterValue` is missing the single qoute to end the string.

Comment: its not the problem,  it heppend when I added it her